# Node-Webkit start function in different window

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

My node-webkit application consists of a control window and a presentation window.

The control window gathers data and eventually launches the presentation window via the `window.open` function.

The presentation window now has access to some information in the `global` variable.

Now I want to render a graphical representation of that information by creating SVG elements and so forth.

I already have a javascript function to do exactly that, but I need some way of starting that function from the control window.

I can't call it directly, since then the function has to access the other window's DOM.

I have tried using the `eval` function on the other window's object, but that crashes node-webkit with the message

```
[18719:0522/205047:ERROR:breakpad_linux.cc(1225)] crash dump file written to 
/tmp/chromium-renderer-minidump-788bf8d0c68301d5.dmp
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Use `setInterval` to regularly check a global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution I've found to be pretty effective is attaching pub/sub functionality to the `global`variable. The setup I've used so far is jQuery-based, though it could also be constructed without. First it is initialized using a variant of [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/) code:

```
    var messages = messages || {};
    global.Message = global.Message || function( id ) {
      var callbacks, method,
      message = id && messages[ id ];
      if ( !message ) {
        callbacks = jQuery.Callbacks();
        message = {
          publish: callbacks.fire,
          subscribe: callbacks.add,
          unsubscribe: callbacks.remove
        };
        if ( id ) {
        messages[ id ] = message;
        }
      }
      return message;
    };
```

Then anywhere between the windows events can be published and subscribed to using the following pattern. One window can publish the data:

```
global.Message("someButtonClicked").publish(data);
```

Then the other can listen for it.

```
global.Message("someButtonClicked").subscribe(onButtonClicked);

function onButtonClicked(data) {
  console.log(data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject and eval a piece of JS by using Window.eval():

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window#windowevalframe-script