# creating custom web interface app using node-webkit and manipulating DOM with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, node-webkit

I want to create a custom web interface/app to a web site. Basically a streamline/custom view of important summary data. The data can be cached locally in the app and updated weekly if there are changes to the source site. I am using two windows. One window I load the html from remote site, the second window I manipulate the DOM/tables of the first window using Javascript to only display information that is important. If there is a better way or tool to do this as I have not found it yet. I am having problems with Javascript not being able to manipulate the DOM of the first window.

Im trying to edit/format the DOM (hide/delete table rows change colors) in the 2nd window from javascript running in the first window (startup node-webkit).
Docs say that I should have universal access to the other windows?  How do I make sure this is true?

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var new_win = gui.Window.get( window.open('http://example.com/index.html'));
var my_elem = new_win.document.getElementById('myelement');
my_elem.style.display='none';
```

Type Error: Cannot read property of 'getElementById' of undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: I outlined one option for multi-window communication in an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815026/node-webkit-start-function-in-different-window/23830075#23830075

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the document property of the new window you have to access it in the window key.

Basically change your line 3 to this:

```
var my_elem = new_win.window.document.getElementById('myelement');
```